# mouseover effect html to auto size for mobile

Tags: html, mobile, mouseover, autosize

I've got a simple mouseover effect on a webpage I'm working on that I'm trying to have auto resize to fit the page so it is more mobile friendly.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  I know I need something like

```
.responsive {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
```

...but I'm not certain how/where to insert it so it works.

Code currently looks like this...

```
<body>
<a href="https://www.bodensurfaces.com/cowboy-trail.html">
<body>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
.responsive {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
.image3 {
 -webkit-transition: all 0.7s ease;
 transition: all 0.7s ease;
} 
.image3:hover {
-webkit-transform:scale(1.1);
transform:scale(1.1);
}
</style>

<img class="image3" src="https://www.bodensurfaces.com/uploads/4/5/8/2/45821353/cowboy-trail-350x250-white-border_orig.png">
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a div to wrap your image, then apply the responsive class to your div. Also set your image width to 100% so it covers the whole div.

```html
<body>
    <a href="https://www.bodensurfaces.com/cowboy-trail.html">
        <body>
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
            <style>
                .responsive {
                    max-width: 100%;
                    height: auto;
                }

                .image3 {
                    width: 100%;
                    -webkit-transition: all 0.7s ease;
                    transition: all 0.7s ease;
                }

                .image3:hover {
                    -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
                    transform: scale(1.1);
                }
                
            </style>
            <div class="responsive">
                <img class="image3"
                    src="https://www.bodensurfaces.com/uploads/4/5/8/2/45821353/cowboy-trail-350x250-white-border_orig.png">
            </div>
        </body>
```

Comment: This worked fantastic.  I made a tweak to force it to the same 350px as the artwork just so it works proper on PC browsing...and what you suggested works fantastic on mobile.  Thank you so much!!  You rock Eveux Pendragon :-)

Comment: @Unclejemima No problem, happy to hear it worked! Please mark the answer as correct to close the question :)